# Azure Recovery Agent has prerequisite of Virtual Server 2005 R2

Tags: azure

I am attempting to install Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent on a Windows 2008 SP2 (Non R2) Enterprise physical server.  The agent is v2.0.9028.0.

Windows Build:  Version 6.0  (Build:  6002:  Service Pack 2)

During the installation the installer shows that Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1 - Enterprise Edition x64 is a required install and it will be installed along with the agent.

This is a physical server with no Virtual or Hyper-V roles.  This server also hosts SQL.  I plan to just backup files and folders.

How can I get around this Virtual Server 2005 requirement?

This does not happen on my 2008 R2 servers.

[Screenshot of Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG3p1.png)

Comment: I went through another channel and found that Windows Server 2008 SP2 DOES require Virtual Server 2005 but this was not documented.   I have been told steps will be taken to update the documentation.

I was given no ETA for was told that an agent is in the works that does not require Virtual Server 2005.